# Monitors whether the task submitted to the thread pool timed out

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a method that will be called all the time.

After calling, a job(runnable) will be generated and submitted to the thread pool. The timeout time of each job is different, depending on the incoming parameters.

Now I want to monitor whether each job can end within the timeout time when it starts to execute. What should I do?

Note that `timeout` is from the beginning of execution to the end of execution, not from the time of delivery to the thread pool to the end of task execution. Because of this, I don't think `future #get (timeout)` can be used, am I right?.

And `acceptJob` should not block, it has to return immediately after submitting the job(maybe some other logic, but not block).

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

public void acceptNewJob(Map<String, Object> params) {
    // timeout from params
    int timeoutInMs = (int) params.get("timeoutInMs");
    pool.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // generate a job by params
            // if this job execute timeout, need alarm
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about wrapping every runnable and use a `Timer` to check the runnable's status when the timeout period expires.

```
    public void acceptNewJob(Map<String, Object> params) {
        // timeout from params
        int timeoutInMs = (int) params.get("timeoutInMs");
        MonitoredRunnable runnable = new MonitoredRunnable(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // generate a job by params
                // if this job execute timeout, need alarm
            }
        }, timeoutInMs);
        pool.submit(runnable);
    }

    // Or use ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor
    private Timer timer = new Timer();

    public class MonitoredRunnable implements Runnable {
        private volatile int state = READY;

        public static final int READY = 0;
        public static final int RUNNING = 1;
        public static final int COMPLETE = 0;

        private Runnable task;
        private int timeoutInMs;

        public MonitoredRunnable(Runnable task, int timeoutInMs) {
            this.task = task;
            this.timeoutInMs = timeoutInMs;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            state = RUNNING;
            startMonitor(this);
            task.run();
            state = COMPLETE;
        }

        private void startMonitor(MonitoredRunnable runnable) {
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    if (runnable.state != COMPLETE) {
                        System.out.println("Job timeout.");
                        // alarm
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //
                }
            }
        }, runnable.timeoutInMs);
    }
```